# BuildConfig could not resolve after upgrading Android Studio to Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

My project ran on the device successfully but when I upgraded my project `BuildConfig` file did not resolve

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1'

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
}
```

I have done `Invalidate Caches...` and `Sync Project with gradle files` but `BuildCongfig` file could not resolve.

I created a new project but in that project same issue exists.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `buildConfig true` to `build.gradle` solved the issue for me.

```
android {
  buildFeatures {
    buildConfig true
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having issue resolving `BuildConfig` in Android Studio Flamingo. By adding this line to `gradle.properties` fixed my issue.

```
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
```